# Opening a Azure Bastion tunnel in a DevOps Pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, azure-bastion

Is it possible to opening a Azure Bastion tunnel in a DevOps Pipeline?
I have successfully done so locally using native client but the tunneling command `az network bastion tunnel` but this results in a locked window until Ctrl-C is sent.

Is it possible to somehow integrate this into a DevOps Pipeline in order to ssh / scp to VM on a private network?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

`az network bastion rdp` and `az network bastion rdp` commands(2) open tunnel, connect with native SSH or RDP client, and finally when the client is disconnected tunnel is being tear-down and az process exits. For SCP you might want to consult https://serverfault.com/questions/522258/file-copying-over-an-already-established-ssh-connection and check if existing SSH connection can be re-used for SCP.

---

Alternative solution: open tunnel with background process. E.g.

```bash
nohup az network bastion tunnel > /dev/null 2>&1 & echo $! > run.pid
scp something
scp something
scp something else
kill -p $(cat run.pid)
```

disclaimer: did not test but this kind of process management should work. If tunnel command requires pty then it is more complicated and requires running tmux or other terminal multiplexer.

---

If you just need to run command(s) on VM `az vm run-command`(1) might also be a good alternative.

---

(1) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/vm/run-command?view=azure-cli-latest

(2) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/network/bastion?view=azure-cli-latest#az-network-bastion-ssh

Comment: Thanks! `az vm run-command` was a great entry point to the `az vm invoke-command` solution which lets me execute commands on the VM. But, then I would need a way (without Bastion) to scp files there without needing a public IP. Any bright ideas?

Comment: Correction: Should be `az vm run-command invoke` and not invoke-command.

Comment: True. Did not remember if invoke is asynchronous or not: command group made more sense than the command itself.

As far as I know there is not management API for file movement. E.g. Azure Devops Copy file task is using WinRM protocol when interacting with VMs

Answer (score 0):

In my use case, we simply appended `&` to the end of the command to make it run in the background.

```bash
az network bastion tunnel &
```

https://www.maketecheasier.com/run-bash-commands-background-linux/